# Changing input value Dynamicaly on Jquery Slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Two Jquery range slider with the range of 7 which is 0-6 . In the first slider when i slide right to left the hidden input value for `colormax` changes from 6 to 0 and for slider left to right `colormin` changes from 0 to 6.

This input value changes when the user slides a handle

```
<input type="hidden" value="0" id="colormin" onchange="modifyresult('colormin',this.value)">
<input type="hidden" value="6" id="colormax" onchange="modifyresult('colormax',this.value)">
```

The following code does it all ..

```
$('#color').slider({ steps: 7, range: true, 
    slide : function(e,ui) {
        $('#colormin').val(parseInt(parseInt($('#color').slider('value', 0))/14));
        $('#colormax').val(parseInt((($('#color').slider('value', 1)))/14)-1);
        $("#ColorLabels td").css("color","white");
        $("#ColorLabels td:lt(" + $('#colormin').val() + ")").css("color", "#666");
        $("#ColorLabels td:gt(" + $('#colormax').val() + ")").css("color", "#666");
    },
    change: function(e,ui) { 
        $('#colormin').val(parseInt(parseInt($('#color').slider('value', 0))/14));
        $('#colormax').val(parseInt((($('#color').slider('value', 1)))/14)-1);
        var colormin = parseInt($('#colormin').val());
        var colormax = parseInt($('#colormax').val());
        $.cookies.set('colormin', colormin);
        $.cookies.set('colormax', colormax);
        $.cookies.set('color1',$('.ui-slider-handle:eq(0)','#color').css("left")); 
        $.cookies.set('color2',$('.ui-slider-handle:eq(1)','#color').css("left")); 
        $.cookies.set('color3',$('.ui-slider-range','#color').css("left")); 
        $.cookies.set('color4',$('.ui-slider-range','#color').css("width")); 
        globalsortname = 'color';
        couplemodifyresult('colormin', colormin, 'colormax', colormax);
    }
});
```

Now if i am to create the second slider with the same range 7 with the name `color2` i can simply duplicate the code but instead of 0-6 i want it to show value within 7-13 .

First i changed the min value in html to 7 and set max to 13 then tried to change in javascript as well in here `slider('value', 0))/14` and here `slider('value', 1)))/14)-1` and played with numbers for a while But could not get it to work .

What calculation i have to do to make it work for second slider to change the value in html hidden input within the range of 7-13

Comment: Can you include a fiddle with a complete example?

Comment: here i have tried but could not get it working ... it returns `NaN` value where it should return 0-6 . http://jsfiddle.net/n3ffE/3/

Comment: However i am using jquery 1.2.6 an UI 1.5.3

Comment: I don't know exactly what your looking for.. I am not seeing your modifyresult functions in the fiddle.. Maybe this will help.. http://jsfiddle.net/n3ffE/4/

Comment: well the `modifyresult` just update the session with the hidden input value. Ok forget my fiddle in your fiddle it works nice but how can i make it like when sliding left to right only the `colormin` will change from 7-13 and colormax will remain unchnaged to 13 till the end . And then same case for right to left the `colormin` will remain unchanged and max will change from 13-7 . Thats what i want.

Comment: Are you saying you would like two slider handlers like in this example?  http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range  Or just one slider handler but depending on which direction you move first to change the color min or colormax?

Comment: What i wanted from your fiddle was when i slide towards right then the right value will not change and same for left .. How ever i have accomplished this by adding +7 ` $('#colormin').val(parseInt(parseInt($('#color').slider('value', 0))/14)+7);` at the end .